# Could not load imported ontology HTTP response code: 403

Tags: java, http, owl, http-status-code-403, owl-api

I have the following ontology (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/ontop/ontop/attachments/Example_MovieOntology/movieontology.owl) stored in OWL File.

I tried to load it:

```
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
File file = new File("movieontology.owl");
OWLOntology ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);
```

But I got this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.UnloadableImportException: Could not load imported ontology: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> Cause: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://dbpedia.org/ontology/at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.makeLoadImportRequest(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1766)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.TripleHandlers$TPImportsHandler.handleTriple(TripleHandlers.java:1537)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.TripleHandlers$HandlerAccessor.handleStreaming(TripleHandlers.java:194)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.OWLRDFConsumer.statementWithResourceValue(OWLRDFConsumer.java:1545)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFParser.statementWithResourceValue(RDFParser.java:370)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.EmptyPropertyElement.startElement(StartRDF.java:236)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.PropertyElementList.startElement(StartRDF.java:658)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFParser.startElement(RDFParser.java:201)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFParser.parse(RDFParser.java:145)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFXMLParser.parse(RDFXMLParser.java:73)
at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.loadOWLOntology(OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.java:197)
at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.actualParse(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1156)
at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1112)
at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1062)
at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1073)
at uk.ac.manchester.owl.owlapi.tutorial.examples.SimpleHierarchyExample.main(SimpleHierarchyExample.java:409)
Caused by: org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.OWLOntologyCreationIOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://dbpedia.org/ontology/
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.loadOWLOntology(OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.java:207)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.actualParse(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1156)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1112)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1014)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadImports(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1723)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.makeLoadImportRequest(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1759)
    ... 29 more
```

If I try to load the ontology through a Web-based Visualization of Ontologies (WebVOWL), it loaded without any problems.
How can I solve?

Comment: Works for me. You should try it again. The URL is online.

Comment: @AKSW I can access to url from browser, but from IDE I got the exception.

Comment: Looks like content negotiation for `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/` doesn't work with imports.

Comment: @AKSW Why does it work with WebVOWL? How can I do?

Comment: WebVOWL doesn't use the OWL API, thus, the imports are probably resolved differently.

Comment: `OWLOntologyManager` has a `setSilentMissingImportsHandling(boolean b)`. you could try that. If not, you should ask for help on the OWL API mailing list

Comment: @AKSW it is missing in OWLAPI 4.0 (https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Migrate-from-version-3.4-and-3.5-to-4.0)

Comment: Ok, but the site explains what to use instead, or not? You have to use the `getOntologyLoaderConfiguration()` and this config` object has a method `setMissingImportHandlingStrategy`

Comment: @AKSW It didn't throw anymore the unload exception, ignoring the import. But I wouldn't overlook it. I would that the loader interprets the `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/` import.

Answer (score 0):

Move to OWLAPI 4.2.3. Content negotiation has been upgraded and should handle any format the caller knows how to parse.

If this dies not work, please raise an issue in the OWLAPI tracker on github.

Comment: I'm already using OWLAPI 4.3.1. It works with suggestion of @AKSW, but ignoring the import.  I would that the owl loader interprets the `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/` import.